# i want to create a file with the system date in another directory and copy some data into it. Unix

Tags: unix

I want to create a file with system date in another directory and copy data difference of two files into it.

```
NOW=$(date +"%H_%D")
file="log_$NOW.txt"

diff tmp1.txt tmp2.txt > $temp/log_$NOW.txt
```

i am using above code. But file is not getting generated. Apart from it if i create a file with simple name i.e without using $NOW the file is getting generated. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The format string to date produces something like `16_12/03/13`. This contains directory separators so the filename becomes invalid. Instead use dots to separate the date:

```
NOW=$(date +"%H_%m.%d.%y")
```

which should produce strings like `16_12.03.13`